# How can I add slickgrid checkboxes to specific rows depending on if a value is true or false, without adding it as a formatter?

Tags: checkbox, slickgrid

Does anyone know how I can add checkboxes only to specific rows in slickgrid without using the formatter approach?

Currently I've just done a columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition()); but that adds checkboxes to all the rows.

When I tried to use the formatter approach like this https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/slickgrid/uKq2aVU5luo I found that when I scrolled through the grid, it would not hold the 'check' that were already selected in the checkboxes of the rows?

Grateful for any help on this.